# Postgres gets out of memory errors despite having plenty of free memory

Tags: postgresql, memory

I have a server running Postgres 9.1.15. The server has 2GB of RAM and no swap. Intermittently Postgres will start getting "out of memory" errors on some SELECTs, and will continue doing so until I restart Postgres *or* some of the clients that are connected to it. What's weird is that when this happens, `free` still reports over 500MB of free memory.

`select version();`:

```
PostgreSQL 9.1.15 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux db 3.2.0-23-virtual #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:29:03 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Postgresql.conf (everything else is commented out/default):

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 500MB
work_mem = 2000kB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
wal_buffers = 16MB
checkpoint_segments = 32
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
random_page_cost = 2.0
effective_cache_size = 1000MB
default_statistics_target = 100
log_temp_files = 0
```

I got these values from [pgtune](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/) (I chose "mixed type of applications") and have been fiddling with them based on what I've read, without making much real progress. At the moment there's 68 connections, which is a typical number (I'm not using pgbouncer or any other connection poolers yet).

`/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.shmmax=1050451968
kernel.shmall=256458

vm.overcommit_ratio=100
vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

I first changed `overcommit_memory` to 2 about a fortnight ago after the OOM killer killed the Postgres server. Prior to that the server had been running fine for a long time. The errors I get now are less catastrophic but much more annoying because they are much more frequent.

I haven't had much luck pinpointing the first event that causes postgres to run "out of memory" - it seems to be different each time. The most recent time it crashed, the first three lines logged were:

```
2015-04-07 05:32:39 UTC ERROR:  out of memory
2015-04-07 05:32:39 UTC DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 125.
2015-04-07 05:32:39 UTC CONTEXT:  automatic analyze of table "xxx.public.delayed_jobs"
TopMemoryContext: 68688 total in 10 blocks; 4560 free (4 chunks); 64128 used
[... snipped heaps of lines which I can provide if they are useful ...]

---

2015-04-07 05:33:58 UTC ERROR:  out of memory
2015-04-07 05:33:58 UTC DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 16.
2015-04-07 05:33:58 UTC STATEMENT:  SELECT oid, typname, typelem, typdelim, typinput FROM pg_type
2015-04-07 05:33:59 UTC LOG:  could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2015-04-07 05:33:59 UTC LOG:  could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2015-04-07 05:33:59 UTC LOG:  could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
TopMemoryContext: 396368 total in 50 blocks; 10160 free (28 chunks); 386208 used
[... snipped heaps of lines which I can provide if they are useful ...]

---

2015-04-07 05:33:59 UTC ERROR:  out of memory
2015-04-07 05:33:59 UTC DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 1840.
2015-04-07 05:33:59 UTC STATEMENT:  SELECT... [nested select with 4 joins, 19 ands, and 2 order bys]
TopMemoryContext: 388176 total in 49 blocks; 17264 free (55 chunks); 370912 used
```

The crash before that, a few hours earlier, just had three instances of that last query as the first three lines of the crash. That query gets run *very* often, so I'm not sure if the issues are *because* of this query, or if it just comes up in the error log because it's a reasonably complex SELECT getting run all the time. That said, here's an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of it: http://explain.depesz.com/s/r00

This is what `ulimit -a` for the postgres user looks like:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15956
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15956
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I'll try and get the exact numbers from `free` next time there's a crash, in the meantime this is a braindump of all the info I have.

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: AFAIK the kernel has to promise memory to processes if it's allocated, even if they're never going to use it. This includes the copy-on-write memory regions `fork()`ed from the postmaster. So even though the memory is free in the sense of not currently being mapped into a process's address space it is committed. I think. I might be totally hand-waving here. It's also possible that some of the kernel's weirdness around accounting for shared memory is at issue.

Comment: `maintenance_work_mem = 128MB` seems quite big given your memory constraints. The fact that the problem occurs when an automatic analyze kicks in, also indicates that this parameter is too large.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've tried setting it to `16MB`. Will report results. Anything else to look out for in the meantime?

Comment: 2 gigs is not a lot of memory with no swap.  Without swap, there's nothing the OS can do if it runs out of memory even for a moment.  And it's [harder for the kernel to defragment memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).  You might have plenty of free memory, but it might all be fragmented.  Consider adding some swap, at least 4 gigs.

Comment: [what the others have said] + lower `max_connections` , except if you *really* need them. Lowering `shared_buffers` ( :- trusting on OS-cache) is also an option (shared memory is locked in core and unswappable in Linux, IIRC) And yes: add some swap.

Comment: @joop rather than lowering `max_connections` do you think it would be worth looking into a connection pooler instead? I'm using 66 out of the 100 at the moment but wary that I might use more in future. For context it's a large Rails app on puma with lots of delayed_job workers.

I added some swap and it's been running a fair bit more stably the last 12 hours, so far so good!

Comment: Running too many connections is a real show stopper (the probability of deadlocks increases exponentially... Also: work_mem is spent on each connection (and possibly on each subquery inside it)) A connection pooler *could* be a good idea. But: RAM is cheap. Swap is even cheaper.  If your OOM killer only kicks in once a day, adding swap would at least would allow the jobs to complete.

Comment: Adding 1gb of swap and decreasing `maintenance_work_mem` has had a big improvement. However, memory usage as reported by `free` does still increase progressively over time (just a lot more slowly). Is there anything else I should be keeping an eye on or being aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if there's any swap memory available when the error raises up?

I've remove completely the swap memory in my Linux desktop (just for testing other things...) and I got the exactly same error! I'm pretty sure that this is what is going on with you too.

Comment: I got this message, and I have swap as well.. Might be the reason for this error...

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this same issue with a ~2.5 GB plain-text SQL file I was trying to restore.  I scaled my Digital Ocean server up to 64 GB RAM, created a 10 GB swap file, and tried again.  I got an out-of-memory error with 50 GB free, and no swap in use.

I scaled back my server to the small 1 GB instance I was using (requiring a reboot) and figured I'd give it another shot for no other reason than I was frustrated.  I started the import and realized I forgot to create my temporary swap file again.

I created it in the middle of the import.  psql made it a *lot* further before crashing.  It made it through 5 additional tables.

I think there must be a bug allocating memory in psql.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit suspicious that you report the same free memory size as your shared_buffers size. Are you sure you are looking the right values?

Output of `free` command at the time of crash would be useful as well as the content of /proc/meminfo

Beware that setting `overcommit_memory` to 2 is not so effective if you see the `overcommit_ratio` to 100. It will basically limits the memory allocation to the size swap (0 in this case) + 100% of physical RAM, which doesn't take into account any space for shared memory and disk caches.

You should probably set `overcommit_ratio` to 50.

Comment: I think that's just a coincidence in how I wrote the question. It was more than 500mb free (as in, "heaps of memory!") rather than a hard value. That said, I think that's a good point on the `overcommit_ratio` - will tinker with that.